# "No route" ruby on rails routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want to change the name in `routes` file.

I have one controller called `wiki_controller`.

I am using another one which have same function as wiki named called FAQ which I don't have a controller.

usually the URL looks like 
`http://example.com/courses/1/wiki/front-page`

I have another button called FAQ. When I click this link, the URL want to change like

`http://example.com/courses/1/FAQ/front-page`

but in the background the controller is wiki but the display URL must be the above.

Comment: Can you list your routes file please?

Answer (score 0):

You can create non-restfull routes like this:

```
get 'courses/:course_id/FAQ/:id', controller: 'wiki', action: :show
```

You can access the route by doing a `GET` request on `/courses/1/FAQ/front-page`, it will hit your `wiki_controller#show`

You can retrieve the variables with `params[:course_id]` and `params[:id]`.

More details on [non-restfull routes here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#non-resourceful-routes)